# How to start model this Film - Camera

Tags: modeling, camera

i'm having trouble modeling this camera body.
Can someone explain me how to start? Should I use modifiers? It would be great if someone could explain a good way! [image: sony fs7]

Answer (score 2):

Choose a side, draw the inner shape, then extrude to get the outer shape:

[image]

[image]

Extrude to give thickness:

[image]

Pull some faces, etc:

[image]

For the other side, first thing hide the part you've already work, switch to the opposite view, and same thing, draw the shapes:

[image]

Then use the back view to pull all these faces:

[image]

[image]

Pull again some of these faces for the second plateau:

[image]

Etc, of course you'll need to rework to have a better topology and you'll need to work all the details

Comment: Thank you! I think the other side is my biggest problem. It would be great if you could explain a way to model it.

Comment: Thank you again! One last question: It was difficult to round off the corners and leave others sharp. How do you get these transitions on the shapes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, to round a vertex you can use the bevel tool (Ctrl B then V to switch form edge bevel to vertex bevel)